# re-running Setup.hs and change detection

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I took the habit of managing my post-install setup things in the `Setup.hs`. The advantages are clear: it's coded in haskell, and it has access to the app data directory, where the binary will get installed.

I'm using it now for instance, to copy the QML data files and icons that a haskell QML application needs to the installation folder.

This all worked well until recently, but now `stack` started optimizing the build a lot, and if it detects that no haskell files changed, it won't re-trigger the `Setup.hs`. That obviously doesn't work for me, because I'd like my QML files and icons to get copied every time I run `stack install` during development.

I can't find a flag for `stack` that would trigger just the `Setup.hs` and nothing else (or little else -- certainly `clean` and `--reconfigure` force rebuilding too many things). How are people doing that? Should I write a shell script? But it'll have trouble finding the target directory for the installation, plus it's less portable that the haskell in my Setup.hs?

I feel stack are probably right in their reasoning and if my current way was really correct they would have enabled this scenario by now. So either there's a stack flag that I don't see, either I'm doing it wrong I think.

*NOTE*: `stack` is so smart that not even `touch Setup.hs` or of another .hs file helps to re-trigger its execution. I must physically change the contents of one file.

*NOTE2*: Ah, I re-discovered `stack path` to find out target path information. I could use that from a shell script to install the files. Still feels like a shame to write that in shell when I have haskell...

*NOTE3*: posted the question [on the stack mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-stack/Vj-9j8P4nek) now...

*NOTE4*: actually [opened a stack bug now](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2357)